# Problems installing and using jsPDF in TypeScript in a .NET MVC project

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF in conjunction with a TypeScript module in a .NET MVC project. I had initial success loading jsPDF from a URL but I wanted to install jsPDF and use the code directly. Before trying this, I loaded jsPDF via

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

in my index.cshtml file and assigned the jsPDF class in the TypeScript module that uses it via

```
const { jsPDF } = window["jspdf"];
```

I currently have all my TypeScript files in a folder called TS-Scripts, which then compiles to JavaScript in a Scripts folder. My tsconfig.json file in the top-level directory (initially) read

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [ "ES6", "DOM" ],
    "outDir": "Scripts/ReportGenerator"
  },
  "include": [
    "TS-Scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The above all worked fine but I wanted to have a local copy of the jsPDF code and call this.

My first step was to install jsPDF in the top-level directory (was this a mistake?) using

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

I commented out the `const { jsPDF } = window["jspdf"];` line above and instead added

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
```

to the top of my TypeScript module. My TypeScript editor then complained about this saying that it could not find the module 'jspdf'. In attempt to remedy this, I then added the line

```
    "moduleResolution": "node",
```

to the tsconfig.json file. This stopped the editor complaining but then when I built the project, I got the build error:

```
tsc : error TS18003: Build:No inputs were found in config file 'C:/Users/MartinVaughan/Documents/Development/GIPortal/node_modules/html2canvas/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["src"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["dist/lib","dist/types"]'
```

Since this was referencing a different tsconfig.json file inside the node_modules folder, I tried renaming the module to 'tsconfig-old.json' to try to get the compiler to ignore it. The build error did then disappear and I was able to build and run the project. However, on inspecting the browser console, I saw the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jspdf". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I am assuming that for some reason when the module is loading, the `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";` line is failing but I am not sure how (or which file) to try loading directly. At this point I am out of ideas.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I am not using Angular or React - just basic TypeScript using the built-in support for this in Visual Studio.